# When I set up multiple home pages in Firefox, I get both/all pages when I click home button

Tags: google-chrome, firefox

When I set up multiple home pages, I get all pages set up as homepage when I click home button . I have set homepage to www.google.co.in/|www.gmail.com . On startup it works fine . It opens both sites but when I click the home button then too it opens both sites . In Chrome it isn't like that . It opens both pages at startup but only 1 when home button is clicked . How to achieve that in Firefox ?

Answer (score 1):

Chrome has the option to open a *specific set of pages* on startup. This is different from the page set as home.

Firefox opens the pages set as home at startup, and when you click the home button. There isn't that distinction found in Google Chrome.

I've looked at the settings you could add to [user.js](http://ilias.ca/archive/userjs), and didn't find anything promising. I think they're all here: [about:config](http://kb.mozillazine.org/About:config_entries).

Wild suggestion: make your own local page that achieves your multitab effect, and set FF to start with it:

```
<!--    This file can reside locally. 
        Note sure if that works, but there's always Stack Overflow.
        http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13295213/jquery-mobile-automatically-open-url-in-new-tab
        http://stackoverflow.com/questions/503093/how-can-i-make-a-redirect-page-in-jquery-javascript
-->
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            setTimeout(function() { 
                window.open("http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0307266567");
                window.location.replace("https://kiva.org");
            }, 1);
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```